# Partialy repair a mongo database

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongodb with my users in it. Users are like that :

```
_id: ObjectId,
created_at: Date,
username: String
```

I don't know why but all my users `created_at` fields have been reset.
I have a save but i can't just use my save and replace all my users by the save because i always have new users. I just need to replace all existing users `created_at` field by their own `created_at` field in the save.

I can use mongoose and node.js to do that (i don't know how but i can find) But i would prefer to do that using only mongodb functions. My saves are on `.bson` format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a local database, put your `.bson` in it. Then do a request to your local db to get all users and save theme in a `.json` file. Then update your user with wrong date with your saved datas.

**Puting your bson file in your database**

```
mongorestore -d yourdatabase -c yourcollection "users.bson"
```

**Set all your good users in a json file**

```
db.model('User').find({}, { created_at: 1 }).exec(function(error, _users) {
    jsonUsers = _users;
    jsonUsers = JSON.stringify(jsonUsers);
    fs.writeFile('myjsonfile.json', jsonUsers, 'utf8', (err) => {

    });
});
```

**Update your wrong users to be good again**

```
const jsonUsers = require('../myjsonfile.json');

db.model('User').find({}, { created_at: 1 }).exec(function(error, _users) {
    if (error) return ;
    _users.forEach((wrongUser) => {
        let goodUser = jsonUsers.find((gU) => { return gU._id == wrongUser._id });
        if (goodUser) {
            wrongUser.created_at = goodUser.created_at;
            wrongUser.save(cb);
        } else {
            //this is on of your new user that where not in your .bson file
        }
    });
});
```